# Getting information about the certain object by clicking the certain image

Tags: java, image, swing, mouselistener, clicking

I made the following class which contains information about users - name, age photo.

```
public class User{

private int age;
private String name;
ImageIcon icon;
JLabel image;

public int getAge() {
return age;
}


public String getName() {
return name;
}


public User(){
this.age = 0;
this.name = "";
}


public User(int age, String name){
this.age = age;
this.name = name;
icon = new ImageIcon(name + ".jpg");
image = new JLabel(icon, JLabel.Center);
}


}
```

I want to create the set of images with users' faces on JPanel. I want to get details of each user after clicking on his photo. So I put this code in the main class:

```
MouseListener myClick = new MouseListener(){

      @Override
      public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
      {
      User selected = new User();   
      selected.image = (JLabel) e.getComponent(); 
      System.out.println(selected.getAge() + " " + selected.getName());

      }
};
```

and

```
User[] users = new User[32];
  for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
       { 
       panel.add(users[i].image);
       users[i].image.addMouseListener(myClick);
       }
```

I know- it is totally wrong. I cannot obtain data about the certain user, because I get values from "selected", which contains only JLabel with image (no values for age or name). 
What should I do to get the name and age of the certain user?

Comment: Display the user icons in a `JList` that contains a collection of users.  When an item (icon) is selected, show the details of that user.  For better help sooner, post a [MCTaRE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Tested and Readable Example).  One way to get image(s) for an example is to hot-link to the images seen in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19209651/418556).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways of achieving what you want to do. (I'm not entirely sure what this is, but I'm sure that there are several ways ;-)).

One interesting question might be who determines the bounds of the images / labels. Are they put into a panel that has a certain layout? When they are, for example, contained in a panel with a `GridLayout` then you can just compute the index of the image based on the "grid cell" that corresponds to a certain mouse position on the panel. If they are positioned freely (on a panel with `null` layout), then you might create a simple map like

```
class ImageMap<T> 
{
    private final Map<Rectangle2D, T> map;

    ImageMap()
    {
        map = new LinkedHashMap<Rectangle2D, T>();
    }

    public T get(double x, double y)
    {
        for (Entry<Rectangle2D, T> entry : map.entrySet())
        {
            Rectangle2D key = entry.getKey();
            if (key.contains(new Point2D.Double(x,y)))
            {
                return entry.getValue();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    void setBounds(T t, Rectangle2D r)
    {
        Rectangle2D copy = new Rectangle2D.Double(
            r.getX(), r.getY(), r.getWidth(), r.getHeight());
        map.put(copy, t);
    }
}
```

Then you can fill this map with the information from the users:

```
ImageMap<User> map = new ImageMap<User>();

List<User> users = ...;
for (User user : users)
{
    map.setBounds(user, user.getImage().getBounds());
}
```

And when you receive a mouse event, you can query this

```
    MouseEvent e = ...;
    User user = map.get(e.getX(), e.getY());
```

But whether this is appropriate really depends on your use-case. Maybe a JList with an appropriate CellRenderer would better suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer to the question but:

1. The constructor of a class, by convention, is defined before the methods of the class.
2. Why did you create a User class with methods `getName()` and `getAge()` but you did not define a `getImage()` method? Be consistent! You should not access variables directly and should define a "getter" method when you want to access data from a class.

Learn from examples and don't make up your own standards.

To follow up on Andrew's comment, you should create a custom renderer to display the Icon from the User class in a JList. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Writing a Custom Cell Renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#renderer) for more information and an example of displaying an Icon. The example uses a JComboBox, but the concept is the same for a JList.

Then you can use a ListSelectionListener to handle selections of the image. This a better approach because this will work when the user uses the mouse or the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar issue with a game I'm working on, and I made a tilePane class. The TilePane class extends a JPanel and has fields for name, age, photo, etc (or just contains a user field). When a photo is clicked, get the parent tilePane, and then get the tilePane's appropriate field. Here's a snippet of my code:

```
public void mouseClick(MouseEvent e) {
...
    } else if (e.getSource() instanceof TilePane) {
                TilePane clickPane = (TilePane) e.getSource();
...
```

Comment: I cannot import TilePane from javafx.scene.layout.TilePane. I am using Netbeans Java - If I would like to use Netbeans JavaFX, I would have to create new project. I don't want to do everything from scratch.

Comment: @Calm I'm not using a JavaFX object; I actually made up my own TilePane class, you can make whatever new class you like, then have it extend a jpanel and attach a mouse listener to it, so it fires your mouse listener and provide's itself as a source. Then you have the object that contains your other data. :)